# Adding a menu item to all windows in C#

Tags: c#, contextmenu, wndproc

I have been trying to find some reference to this for a couple days now, and the only thing I can find is how to add menu items to your form's context menu.

I am wanting to manipulate all windows' context menus to include a custom menu item.

Conceptually, I think I'm going to have to loop through and grab the handles of all processes and intercept their context menus and override the WndProc() method per process, but I'm struggling to find information to point me in the right direction.

Comment: If by *all windows* you mean `Explorer`, `Desktop` etc,  you can do this using [ShellExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx).  If you wish to add something to every window ever created - I could see some real design issues you may wish to consider - for example, a Game, is technically also a Window.

Comment: You are correct about the second part... I wanting to manipulate all windows' context menus, not all Windows'. Every running program that has the context menu when you right click on the title bar. I am wanting to insert a custom item (preferably at the top) into every programs' title bar's context menu.

Comment: To do the second part, you could scan for new applications being launched and then check if those applications are "windows" -- not all applications have windows (services, etc).  The scanner would then, on launch -- give time for the application to launch fully (different programs finish loading at certain speeds).  Then, you would hook the 'close' menu as you request, and manipulate it normally.  You might want to start a blacklist of programs that you don't wish to attach to.  To attach to dialogs, you will need to monitor for all api calls (like Spy++) and attach that way.

Comment: There are some **very** serious design flaws in doing this which will break an unknown (but confident a fairly large) number of programs. Programming makes very few things impossible, but just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should be.  I would take great care and reconsider design implications as well as exhausting resources/etc, before implementing such a dangerous *feature*. In any case, if you do choose to proceed, I wish you best of luck following my directions down the deep dark rabbit-hole.

Comment: Well, no need to poll for new applications, it's possible to [have a DLL preloaded into every application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/197571) (well, all the ones that use certain system DLLs, but it's a DLL which is needed for creating a window, so you'll get the ones you need).  Another method is to hook into window creation using `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: Please note that no matter approach you use for code injection, only native code should ever be injected into other processes, and absolute minimum dependencies (i.e. `kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll`, `gdi32.dll`, and maybe `advapi.dll`)  You really, *really*, don't want to cause .NET initialization in processes that aren't designed for it, or even worse, use the .NET hosting APIs to customize behavior.  Either you'll end up in the custom .NET environment behaving badly, or you'll prevent the custom environment from starting at all.  Both outcomes are very bad.

Comment: Also, what you're calling a context menu is actually the **system menu** (`GetSystemMenu()` function and `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message).  It's been opened by left-click in an area left of the window title bar, or Alt+Space, for many Windows versions.  The right-click on title bar is much more recent.